# Laravel does not run validator on empty string

Tags: laravel

I have custom validator.

```
Validator::extend('custom_validator', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
         return $value === '1';
});
```

And then how I validate

```
$v = Validator::make(['test' => 'a'], ['test' => 'custom_validator']);
$v->errors()->all(); // returns [
     "validation.custom_validator",
   ]
```

But when I pass string which contains only spaces

```
$v = Validator::make(['test' => '     '], ['test' => 'custom_validator']);
$v->errors()->all(); // returns [], so validator passed what is wrong
```

So why validator does not run my custom validation function for this string?

Comment: Have you tried `Validator::extendImplicit()` ?

Comment: But this field is not required and when I do not pass it in request validation fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
Validator::extendImplicit('custom_validator', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    if($value === null) return true; // this line checks for 'empty' strings
    return $value === '1';
});
```

I had to use `extendImplicit` instead of `extend` method, because `extendImplicit` validates all strings, but `extend` does not validate empty strings (because internally laravel runs `trim` function on input data and if string is empty, then validator is not executed at all!)

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.